# related rate problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

two fast ants start traveling from the same point in the sand. one ant heads north at a rate of 2cm/s and the other Ant travels east @ a rate of 3cm/s. the trails the ant leave form the sides of a right triangle. how fast is the area of the triangle increasing after 5 seconds.

i took the following approach  i know the area of a triangle is 
$$\frac{1}{2}bh$$
and im given that the base of my triangle is changing at a rate of 3 cm's and my height if changing at a rate of 2 cm's therefore i said.
$$\frac{dh}{dt} = 2 $$
$$\frac{db}{dt} = 3 $$

so i take the derivative of my triangle formula 
and i end up with
$$A \frac{da}{dt}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{db}{dt} \frac{dh}{dt}$$ 
substituting the values in 
im solving for $\frac{da}{dt}$
$$5\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}*2*3 $$
$$\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{3}{5}cm/s$$
did i approach this correctly? i would love know if i did this correctly but im not 100% sure. I like to get someones second opinion on it.
Thanks
Miguel

Comment: Be careful, the derivative of a product is not the product of the derivatives : $(uv)'=u'v+uv'\neq u'v'$ ;)

Comment: Since the area of the triangle $a = \frac{1}{2} bh$ involves a product, don't you want to use the Product Rule when you implicitly differentiate $a$ ?  Also, what is $A$ and why have you inserted 5 (seconds) there?

Comment: also your units should be $cm^2/sec$.  This is another hint for the product rule.  If you evaluate your units they don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).  From $a=\frac 12bh$ you get $a'=\frac 12 b'h+\frac 12 bh'$

Added:  See if the below figure helps.  I drew a rectangle because it seemed clearer.  At any time, the rectangle area is $a=bh$.  If $b$ and $h$ both increase by $db$ and $dh$ we add the two long rectangles $db \times h$ and $dh \times b$  The small $dh \times db$ is negligible.

[image]

Comment: so should it be $$\frac{dh}{dt}+\frac{db}{dt} $$? iw that where i went wrong?

Comment: @Miguel:  no, it should be $\frac 12(b\frac {dh}{dt}+h\frac {db}{dt})$.  This should be in your text.

Comment: thank you i get it now.  i see where i went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what you just said, you know the derivative of both sides: $\frac{dh}{dt}=2$ and $\frac{db}{dt}=3$.

This tells you that $h=2t+h_0$ and $b=3t+b_0$.

Here $h_0=b_0=0$ so $h=2t$ and $b=3t$. Thus $A=\frac{1}{2}(2t)(3t)=3t^2$.

You can now say that $\frac{dA}{dt}=6t$

Now you know how fast it goes after 5 seconds ($t=5$)

Comment: Just something you should check which could help you spot a mistake: if you're working with an area and both sides are evolving at fixed rate, then it's evolving at a squared rate. Which means the rate increases as time goes by. If it's a volume then it's some cubed rate, which means the rate at which the rate evolves is increasing. And so on ...

Comment: thank you this is very helpful.